# asp.net MVC webmatrix membershipprovider kicking in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

after migrating from mvc2 - mvc3 with minor issues ... I encounter the following problem when calling Membership.GetAllUsers

it seems that instead of System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider is kicking in. I am using WebMatrix to get razor helpers to work with MVC3. Tried a bunch of things but without success.

IIS7 administration config looks like this

```
        <trustedProviders allowUntrustedProviders="false">
            <add type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </trustedProviders>
```

> [NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
>      WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords) +28
>      System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords) +45

Comment: can you please share, how did you resolve this? Removing WebMatrix would mean not being able to use those helpers anymore, in my case I want to keep using those helpers from webmatrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta there was a bug where some additional features were enabled by mistake. There are some config settings to disable them, but they shouldn't be needed anymore.

In ASP.NET MVC 3 RC (which was released earlier this week) they should all be fixed. You'll want to make sure that in your web.config files and project references you are not referencing any of the "WebMatrix" DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

What about your web.config, specifically the [system.web.membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b9hw62f.aspx) section?

```
<system.web>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
<system.web>
```

Comment: Nope. It is in there. If I remove the WebMatrix assembly from web.config everything works fine. Could actually see through Reflector that the mehtod in Webmatrix throws NotSupportedException but I don't know why and how WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

found solution. Seems that changing the defaultProvider to another setting is the solution. I guess WebMatrix was registers using "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" as it's name -> but's a guess unfortunately

```
<membership defaultProvider="SQL">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SQL" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="images" passwordFormat="Clear" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```